# Problem with scraping angularjs website? using file_get_contents

Tags: php, angularjs, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am **scraping** an angularjs website using file_get_contents as well as using curl, but as an output I get incomplete html page. When I reviewed the html file, than I found that the content of *div with ui-view* attribute is not getting retrieved.

Is any other way of **scraping** the angularjs site, which can provide me the complete html of the page? I Google it and found that I can use phantomjs or casperjs to scrape an angularjs website but those are command line scripts. In my case I want to access my **scraper** using browser.

Comment: Your browser can't use file_get_contents. Your browser can't use curl. You're just using PHP libraries. Write PHP to wrap phantomjs or casperjs or find an existing PHP library that does it for you.

Comment: @OP Did you find the correct method to do it ?